# "advantage of " VS "advantage with"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. Another important advantage **with** the Mobile Miner is the fact that it can produce tunnels at the same cost as drill and blast, but the efficiency is higher due to the continuous excavation.
> 2. Another important advantage **of** the Mobile Miner is the fact that it can produce tunnels at the same cost as drill and blast, but the efficiency is higher due to the continuous excavation.

The Mobile Miner is a mecanical rock-cutting system, or more generally, a mining machine.
I have had the impression that of is followed by the word advantage. Why here with is used?

Answer (score 1):

> An advantage **with** the Mobile Miner

and

> An advantage **of** the Mobile Miner

mean pretty much the same thing. I believe **of** may be the preferred preposition in formal use. My personal impression is that **of** more directly states that the advantage is a consequence or property of the subsequent noun, whereas **with** may show that the advantage merely occurs in the scenario involving the subsequent noun.